# angular 5 - how get subscribe component from service

Tags: angular, subscribe

I would like get data in service , but i don't know how do it.

This is my methode service calendar:

```html
  setWbsRdv(RDV: CalendarModel) {//enregistre le rendez-vous
    this._http.post<CalendarModel>(this.wbsSaveDate, { RDV }).subscribe((data) => {
      return data; //if console.log(data) is retourn "save ok"
    }, (error) => {
    })
```

this is my component is call service calendar

```js
  validRDV() {
   // console.log(this._RDV);
    this._visiteur.getWbsJwt().subscribe(
      apiJwt => {
        this._visiteur.jeton = apiJwt;//enregistrement du jeton pour une utilisation ultérieure un autre composant
        this._RDV.setJwt(apiJwt); // !! important injecter le jeton dans l'objet RDV
        let reponse = this._calendarService.setWbsRdv(this._RDV); //enregistrement du RDV   
        console.log(response);

      }
    );
  }
```

the console.log(response) is undifined , how correctly to load this response for
show in my template ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You need inside the `getWbsJwt().subscribe` again subscribe to the `setWbsRdv`. Remove the `subscribe` part from the `setWbsRdv` and move into the component.

```
apiJwt => {
    this._visiteur.jeton = apiJwt;
    this._RDV.setJwt(apiJwt);
    this._calendarService.setWbsRdv(this._RDV).subscribe(here your logic);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not implement 'subscribe' in your service.
'subscribe must be implemented by the consumer you use.
Please code as below.

```html
  setWbsRdv(RDV: CalendarModel) {
   return this._http.post<CalendarModel>(this.wbsSaveDate, { RDV });
}
```

```js
  validRDV() {
   // console.log(this._RDV);
    this._visiteur.getWbsJwt().subscribe(
      apiJwt => {
        this._visiteur.jeton = apiJwt;//enregistrement du jeton pour une utilisation ultérieure un autre composant
        this._RDV.setJwt(apiJwt); // !! important injecter le jeton dans l'objet RDV
        let reponse = this._calendarService.setWbsRdv(this._RDV).subscribe((data) => {
      return data; //if console.log(data) is retourn "save ok"
    }, (error) => {
    }); //enregistrement du RDV   
        console.log(response);

      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use rxjs catch/throw operators and combine them with an Observable in your service. Do it like this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

errorHandler (error) {
    return Observable.throw(error.error.message)
  }

testFunction (body): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
    .post('some-route', body, httpOptions)
    .catch(this.errorHandler)
  }

}
```

And in your component do it like this:

```
this._myService.testFunction(bodyObject).subscribe(
    res => {
        // this block is executed if you receive a valid response from your server
    },
    err => {
        // here is here your Observable will throw an error if it occurs
        // this block is executed if you receive an error from your server
    }
)
```

This is by far the best approach to keep your code clean and well organized.